# Django forms: what happens when the submit button is pressed

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working through the documentation of Django and I don't fully understand what happens when the submit button is pressed in a form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/

In varous examples the target URL seems to be determined by the HRML file and the submit button will forward to /your-name/ in this example:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I find it confusing that at the same time in the view it is expected to be forwarded to /thanks/ with the HttpResponseRedirect. Are both necessary, and do they have different purposes? Isn't there a way to handle everything from the view rather than the html file?

```
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: its probably doing a redirect so that if you reload the page it does not resubmit the data

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening

Comment: I guarantee thats what they are showing, there  is absolutely nothing that "requires a redirect", its just good practice when dealing with submitted data... but to answer your question it does the same thing antime a form has method="post" and a submit button ... it submits the form data to the url specified as post data ...

Comment: ok so there's no way of handling that from the view?

Comment: you could use javascript to submit it via ajax(as opposed to submitting it via form.submit, which is essentially what the submit button does) ... your question doesnt really make sense ... this has nothing at all to do with python this is just how html/js/backends work ...

Comment: 'ctrl' + 'shift' - 'i' will open the debugger in Firefox or Chrome. Click the network tab, the press 'submit'. It will show you details of the request that is sent when you click the submit button (click on the request for more information about it - it will show you form parameters that get sent).